# Is there a way to list all available institution IDs?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Our use case is: the user selects the institution he wants to connect to and then inputs his credentials to grant us access to his data.

For that, we need to list all institutions available for the user to choose from and then connect through OAuth via Banno API.

I know I can extract the institution's details from [this endpoint](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/institutions/details/#/Institution%20Details/fetchInstitutionAbilities), but I need the institution ID as a parameter.

Where do I get this ID from? Is there a way to list all available IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The short answer

There isn't an API that would return the full list of Banno-powered institutions.

### The long answer

Each Banno-powered financial institution is--by definition--its own developer platform via the [Digital Toolkit and how it empowers institutions for open banking](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/open-banking/).

The Banno Admin back office administrator at each financial institution could [configure an External Application](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/overview/configuration/) for you and provide you with a Client ID + Client Secret for accessing their institution via OAuth + OpenID Connect. Institutions should know their own `institutionId` (and if they do not, then they can discover it via network traffic in the browser's dev tools).

- Notably, you would have to figure out for yourself *which* institutions are Banno-powered since there isn't any publicly available listing nor API for that purpose.